# Negative value not being added to Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, if-statement

**Problem**

I have 2 arrays, one for positive numbers, one for negative numbers. For some reason, if the first number to be added is a negative number, it creates the array space to add the number yet the number inserted will always be 0.

**Code for adding**

Here is my add method, it determines if the value is negative or positive and adds the value to the appropriate array:

```
bool MyClass::addInt(int valueToBeInserted){

 if (valueToBeInserted >= 0){
    if (posArrayIterator >= sizeOfMyArray){
      return false;
    } else {
      cout << "added " <<  valueToBeInserted << "\n" << endl;
      myPArray[posArrayIterator] = valueToBeInserted;
      posArrayIterator ++;
      return true;
    } 
  } else {
    if (negArrayIterator >= sizeOfMyArray){
      return false;
    } else {
      cout << "added " <<  valueToBeInserted << "\n" << endl;
      myNarray[negArrayIterator] = valueToBeInserted;
      negArrayIterator ++;
      return true;
    }
  }

}
```

**Output**

With the following test:

```
b.addInt(-1);
b.addInt(-3);
b.addInt(-9);
```

The expected output would be

```
[-1, -3, -9]
```

but output is

```
[-3, -9, 0].
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: try and avoid global variables.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I believe that  bug is not in the code presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not posting the whole class I can only guess where the problem is.

1) Are `posArrayIterator` and `negArrayIterator` initialized to `0`? They should be!

2) What is a value of `sizeOfMyArray`?

There is nothing wrong with your `bool MyClass::addInt(int valueToBeInserted)`

See example below:

```
class  MyClass
{
 private:
 int sizeOfMyArray;
 int posArrayIterator;
 int negArrayIterator;
 int myNarray[20];
 int myPArray[20];    

 public:
 MyClass(){
     sizeOfMyArray = 20;
     posArrayIterator = 0;
     negArrayIterator = 0;
  };

 bool addInt(int value); 
 void printNArray()
 {
   cout << "[ ";
   for (int i=0; i<negArrayIterator; i++)
   {
     cout << myNarray[i];
     if ( (i+1) < negArrayIterator ) 
     {
         cout << ", "; 
     }
   }
   cout << "]";
 }
};

 bool MyClass::addInt(int valueToBeInserted){

 if (valueToBeInserted >= 0){
    if (posArrayIterator >= sizeOfMyArray){
      return false;
    } else {
      cout << "added " <<  valueToBeInserted << "\n" << endl;
      myPArray[posArrayIterator] = valueToBeInserted;
      posArrayIterator ++;
      return true;
    } 
 } else {
        if (negArrayIterator >= sizeOfMyArray){
            return false;
        }
        else {
           cout << "added " <<  valueToBeInserted << "\n" << endl;
           myNarray[negArrayIterator] = valueToBeInserted;
           negArrayIterator ++;
           return true;
      }
 }
}

int main()
 {
  MyClass b;
  b.addInt(-1);
  b.addInt(-3);
  b.addInt(-9);
  b.printNArray();
  return 0;
 }
```

Output:

```
added -1

added -3

added -9

[ -1, -3, -9]
```

Comment: posArrayIterator and negArrayIterator are both initalised to 0 in the constructor. Also sizeOfMyArray is set in the constructor to 20, its a fixed constant for the size of the arrays

Comment: @TerribleCoderSad Please post the whole class and I will help you.

Comment: @TerribleCoderSad was my example helpful? Do you need more help?

Comment: My operator methods turned out to be the problem

Comment: @TerribleCoderSad I am glad that you have found the problem. If my answer was useful you can mark it as useful by clicking on arrow up. Thank you!